# Implementing NTP server side

Tags: c, ntp

Good evening,
i need to write an NTP server for my studies. It should have the most basic functions and it must be in C.
Anyway, this work is something i don't even know what to start with. Would someone suggest some literature on how to handle packages, and basic functions. A simple NTP server source would serve me as well.

Comment: NTP or FTP? They are different things.

Comment: See http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc959.html for the FTP specification. A client will send commands such as `GET` and `PUT` and will expect your server to respond appropriately.

Comment: My mistake, i mean NTP. Lack of sleep

Comment: The NTP server is open source. You could look into that, at least for the algorithm part. comp.protocols.time.ntp is/was also one of the last usenet groups with decent activity.

Comment: BTW: there is no such thing as *a simple NTP server*. NTP is extremely hard, both from the theoretical side (synchronising / PLLs) and the technical (network stuff; avoiding latency) side. Don't expect to reach the same level of perfection as David Mills et.al. reached in 20+ years of effort. You should be glad if you got a working prototype within a few months.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search or a search on Wikipedia should/could have answered this question for you very quickly.

Note there is something literally called "Simple NTP", or SNTP, described in RFC-5905 Section 14 (5905 is the full specification for the complete NTPv4 protocol).  Note that RFC-5905 even includes skeleton code for a server in C.  There are numerous SNTP clients available, including one in the official [NTP Reference Implementation](http://www.ntp.org/)